# delphi mysql query result

Tags: mysql, delphi

for read data from database server im using mysql query like this:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from `table` WHERE dcid=3;';
FDQuery1.Open;
memo1.Lines.Add( FDQuery1.FieldByName('value').AsString );
```

but when i have to use a loop for read data from mysql

**i need a array to read and store data on it**

i know in php its like this

```
$arr = array();
while($obj = $q->fetch_object() ){
    $arr[] = $obj;
}
```

but how can i do this syntax in Delphi ?

Comment: Look at e.g. First, Next, Eof.

Comment: i know seek on rows,my question is about the variable that store data on it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. In PHP your array will hold the information of the whole record? If so, I do not know an exact equivalent in Delphi.

Comment: I dont think there is such thing in delphi. You could make a Record with the same fields as your row in the database, and make an array of that record type. But you need to fill it yourself using loops again. But why do you need an array ? Why not use FQuery1 in stead ?

Comment: There is the internal storage table row object (`FDQuery1.Table.Rows[Index]`) which one can take as a row object. But what's behind this? What is the exact aim?

Comment: @GuidoG because FQuery1 is busy until i need its recorded data,when i have to do a new query i must add a new FQuery and so...

Comment: FQuery1 is going to be busy anyway populating the array. It's got to be in use while the data is being read. This sounds very much like an XY question. Explain the X that's causing you to try to hack around it using Y.

Comment: Why dont you explain to us what you are trying to accomplish here. It sounds like your looking for a hack so very probably there will be a better way of doing what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I have altered my answer to store all of your data in a 2D array, laid out in the same way as the query result. Is that what you want (see the bottom bit of code)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do FDQuery1.First as that is implicit in the FDQuery1.Open. However if you want to know how many records you have it's important to do a FDQuery1.Last; before using FDQuery1.RecordCount to get the true record count otherwise you might get strange results.

All you need to do get your data into a memo is this

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from table WHERE dcid=3;';
memo1.Lines.clear;
FDQuery1.Open;
While not FDQuery1.Eof do
    begin
    memo1.Lines.Add( FDQuery1.FieldByName('value').AsString );
    FDQuery1.next;  
    end;
end;
FDQuery1.Close;
```

although a better solution with minimal exception handling is

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from table WHERE dcid=3;';
memo1.Lines.clear;
try
try
   begin
     FDQuery1.Open;
    While not FDQuery1.Eof do
        begin
        memo1.Lines.Add( FDQuery1.FieldByName('value').AsString );
        FDQuery1.next;  
        end;
    end;
     end;
except
 on E : Exception do
     begin
       showmessage ('Exception class name = '+E.ClassName+ slinebreak
                 +  'Exception message = '+E.Message);
      end  //on E
end; //try-except

finally
 FDQuery1.Close;
end; //try-finally
```

You mention an array. This is not needed if you only want to put the data in a memo but if you *did* want to put the data in an array (a dynamic array of variants as you don't know at design time how many record elements you need, how many field elements you need or what type each field is) then you would use the following code.

(Note this is deliberately not optimised code as I was trying to make the process clear)

```
Const
  FirstRecordIndex = 0;
  FirstFieldIndex = 0;

Var 
  DataArray : Variant;
  TheRecordCount, TheFieldCount,
  RecordNumber, FieldNumber : integer;
  Data : variant;

begin
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from table WHERE dcid=3;';
FDQuery1.Open;

FDQuery1.Last; //to get correct recordcount
TheRecordCount := FDQuery1.RecordCount;
TheFieldCount := FDQuery1.FieldCount;
FDQuery1.First; //go back to the beginning of the dataset

//set the dimensions of the 2D array of variants to hold data
DataArray := VarArrayCreate([FirstRecordIndex, TheRecordCount, FirstFieldIndex, TheFieldCount], varVariant ); //element can be of any type

//fill it
RecordNumber := -1;  //initialise record indexe to just before the start
While not FDQuery1.Eof do
        begin
        inc(RecordNumber); //point to next record element in the array
        for FieldNumber := FirstFieldIndex to TheFieldCount -1 do  //load all the fields of this record
           begin
           Data := FDQuery1.Fields[FieldNumber].asVariant; //get the data
           DataArray[RecordNumber, FieldNumber] := Data;  //put into array
           end;
        FDQuery1.next;  //get next record
        end; //while
    end;
    FDQuery1.Close;
end;
```

To get the data back again use

```
For RecordNumber := FirstRecordIndex  to  TheRecordCount -1 do
    For FieldNumber := FirstFieldIndex to TheFieldCount -1 do
            begin
            Data := DataArray[RecordNumber, FieldNumber] ;
           //do something with the data ie put into a memo
            end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, i hope that help u:

```
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from `table` WHERE dcid=3;';
FDQuery1.Open;
if FDQuery1.Active and (FDQuery1.RecordCount > 0) then
begin
    FDQuery1.First;
    While not FDQuery1.Eof do
    begin
        memo1.Lines.Add( FDQuery1.FieldByName('value').AsString );
        FDQuery1.next;  
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with array of array consept

for this first you must create your new type

```
type
  myArray = array [1..10] of integer;
  myData= array of myArray;
```

and then you must define your variable

```
var
  Records: myData;
  i:integer;
```

on,now we have aarray of array to save database records on it so

```
begin
FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from table WHERE type=3;';
FDQuery1.Open;
FDQuery1.First;

SetLength(Records ,FDQuery1.recordcount);//or maybe you need a do a select count(*) query first
i:=0;

While not FDQuery1.Eof do
  begin
        Records[i][1]:= FDQuery1.FieldByName('value1').AsString;
        Records[i][2]:= FDQuery1.FieldByName('value2').AsString;
        Records[i][3]:= FDQuery1.FieldByName('value3').AsString;
        Records[i][4]:= FDQuery1.FieldByName('value4').AsString;
        Records[i][5]:= FDQuery1.FieldByName('value5').AsString;
        Records[i][6]:= FDQuery1.FieldByName('value6').AsString;
    i:=i+1;
        FDQuery1.next;
  end;
    FDQuery1.Close;   
end;
```

now all of your selected database records are in your local variable
you can go over the row and make new queries with FDQuery1...